# How to stop Nemo 20.04 double-click behavior

Tags: 20.04, budgie, nemo, doubleclick

I am using Ubuntu Budgie 20.04 and I am struggling with a new feature in the file manager.

When you are double-clicking your way down through a stack of folders, if you accidentally double-click in the white space (rather than on a folder), it actually goes **up one level** which is very disorienting when you are expecting it to drill down.

I am sure someone thought this feature is great, and perhaps some like it. However, I just want to disable it.

Is there a way?

Comment: Is there really no way to stop this? I guess I will uninstall it and change to Nautilus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open up your terminal and type the following two commands to disable double-click from going up one folder:

```
gsettings set org.nemo.preferences click-double-parent-folder false

sudo gsettings set org.nemo.preferences click-double-parent-folder false
```

https://github.com/zilexa/UbuntuBudgie-config/blob/0aea42ab46b7bd949be32245bbff0ccd6d48e503/postinstall.sh#L88

Comment: Wonderful. No need for sudo. Thanks!